# Hive grant permission on database scope

Tags: hadoop, hive, acl

Is it possible to grant all tables on hive database.

HBase have support to grant permission at global scope, namespace scope and goes up to Column qualifier.

I have configured SQL standard based authorization in hive.

Is it possible to grant permission on database directly instead of particular table or view?

`grant select on database database_name to user user_name`

Is there option to achieve the above command in hive native sql standard based authorization.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With basic auth this is not possible.
You need to use/enable sentry(cloudera) or ranger(hortonworks) for this fine permissions.